# restore untracked files after git stash

Tags: git, github, restore

I created a new repo in github and cloned it inside my already existing project directory in my machine. I migrated specific folders into the cloned project and added a .gitignore to ignore images and track only folders with .py and .ipynb files in it.

When I

> git status

I only saw that I can add .gitignore and not the folders that contain the files I want. I pushed it to github and (as expected) saw only .gitignore added in my remote repo.

I thought I cannot add the folders with files I want so I would like to revert to original state (without the gitignore).

Unfortunately, I did

> git stash

Now, my original .py and .ipynb files that are not written in .gitignore are gone. How can I retrieve them? I do not have duplicate copies of the project.

Comment: try `git stash apply`

Answer (score 0):

You do a git stash pop to get it back.

Comment: It still did not restore my original untracked files. Any more suggestions?

Comment: that will restore only tracked files

Answer (score 0):

If the untracked files were inside the directories you put in `.gitignore`, then it's probably lost (I encountered this problem when i put directories to be ignored as `dir/*` format instead of `dir/` in the `.gitignore` file.
I believe this bug has been solved in version 2.14.0
(https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.14.0.txt#L384)